# Finding Screen width and Screen Height in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

how to find the screen width and screen height using java script

Comment: U could use the variables outside your `$.post`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? You already have the screen dimensions. Are you trying to get some responsive content?

Comment: @t0m I only ask because it makes more sense to store this data in a cookie, then read it on the http request for that page.

Comment: @t0m With regards to setting the cookie if you do want to try it: http://css-tricks.com/make-client-side-data-available-server-side/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Answer

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9rBdx/561/)

```
JS

$("#width").val($(window).width());
$("#height").val($(window).height());

HTML

Width<input type="text" name="width" id="width">
Heigth<input type="text" name="height" id="height">
```

Comment: Not sure how this stores the value server-side...

Comment: @t0m : what you need more?

Answer (score 1):

I think this ill do the trick
JQuery:

```
var Width = $(window).width();
var Height = $(window).height();
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for this

```
// Get the window dimensions
var $window = $(window);
var wWidth  = $window.width();
var wHeight = $window.height();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$(function() {
    $.post(window.location, { width: screen.width, height:screen.height }
});
```

Comment: This seems to be the only answer that actually takes PHP into account. Not sure if it works thought as I can't test it myself.

Comment: Why can't we do it in ajax ?it is more reliable when using jquery and result will be consistent

Comment: $.post() internally issues an ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

Finding height and width in `%`

```
var getPercent = function(elem){
var elemName = elem.attr("id");
var width = elem.width();
var height = elem.height();
var parentWidth = elem.offsetParent().width();
var percentWidth = Math.round(100*width/parentWidth);

var parentHeight = elem.offsetParent().height();
var percentHeight = Math.round(100*height/parentHeight);

console.log(elemName+"'s width = "+percent+"%");
console.log(elemName+"'s height = "+percent+"%");
}

getPercent($('#content'));
```

Instead of writing `post.php` to post it to the new page use `window.location` instead
PHP would use it like:

```
$(function() {
$.post(window.location, { width: screen.width, height:screen.height }
});
```